# Column wise logical operation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

What is the correct way to make logical operation between the columns of numpy array?

For now I found:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(3, 10, (5, 4))
col_or = np.sum(x > 8, axis=1) != 0
col_and = np.prod(x > 8, axis=1) != 0
```

It bothers me that I need to convert the logical values to numeric values and the logical operations to regular arithmetic operations. In addition, I also need to check for inequality (`!= 0`)

Is there more appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: Have you condidered `all` or `any`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be using [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) and [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) for your operations. Not only are they more efficient in terms of how the check is carried out, but they short-circuit.

I realize that this is just an example, but I would avoid recomputing the mask multiple times as well:

```
mask = x > 8
col_or = np.any(mask, axis=1)
col_and = np.all(mask, axis=1)
```

You can also use the [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html) and [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html) methods of the array itself:

```
col_or = mask.any(axis=1)
col_and = mask.all(axis=1)
```